# Google Bigtable python api rowkey regex filter issues

Tags: regex, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, bigtable

Recently I've been trying to get data from our Bigtable tables using python. I'm able to connect and authenticate with the api, and I can get some sample data, but when I go to add a simple rowkey regex filter I get an empty data set, even though I know there should be data there.

All the rowkeys have a format like this:

```
XY_1234567_Z
```

where X and Y are capital letters A-Z and Z is a number 0-9. The `_1234567_` is the constant that I provide. **So basically I need to get all rows where rowkey is everything that contains `_1234567_` for example.**

This is the regex I use:

```
^.._1234567_.$
```

And this an example of my current code:

```
...
tbl            = instance.table(tableID)
regex          = ("^.._" + str(rowID) + "_.$").encode()
fltr           = RowKeyRegexFilter(regex)
row_data       = tbl.read_rows(filter_=fltr)
print(row_data.rows)
```

row_data.rows always ends up being an empty dict. I've tried removing `encode()` and just sending a string, and I've also tried a different regex to be more specific like this `"([A-Z][A-Z])_" + str(rowID) + "_([0-9])"` which still didn't work. If I try to do row_data.consume_next(), it hangs for a while and eventually gives me a `StopIteration` error. I've also tested the regex with regex101 and that seems to be fine, so I'm not sure where the issue is.

Comment: You may need to use the \C escape character. You are encouraged to read the Note:
"Special care need be used with the expression used. Since each of these properties can contain arbitrary bytes, the \C escape sequence must be used if a true wildcard is desired. The . character will not match the new line character \n, which may be present in a binary value."
More detail on the [Bigtable Row Filters](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/row-filters.html#google.cloud.bigtable.row_filters.RowKeyRegexFilter) documentation page, RowKeyRegexFilter entry.

Comment: @George I just tried replacing the '.' with '\C' and I still get the same empty dict result, even though the only possible characters are capital letters and numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've already figured it out, but please see the documentation for the python Data API [1, 2]. Calling row_data.consume_next() will fetch the next ReadRowsResponse in the stream and store it in row_data.rows. consume_next() will raise a StopIteration exception when there are no more results to consume. Alternatively, you can call row_data.consume_all() to consume all of the results from the stream (up to an optional limit).

[1] https://googleapis.dev/python/bigtable/latest/data-api.html?highlight=consume_next#stream-many-rows-from-a-table

[2] https://gcloud-python-bigtable.readthedocs.io/en/data-api-complete/row-data.html#gcloud_bigtable.row_data.PartialRowsData

Answer (score 0):

It seems all I needed to do was row_data.consume_next() to get the set of data I requested. Stupid mistake. The row_data object is initially an empty dict but is populated once consume_next() reads the next item in the stream. This brought up a new issue where consume_next() would hang if read_rows() didn't find any match, but this is for another question.